# How can I see the compilation time on Overleaf?

Tags: compiling, overleaf

Overleaf has showed me this warning for the first time:

[image]

I thought that document was comfortably well under the 1-minute limit for free Overleaf plans.

How can I see the compilation time on Overleaf?

Comment: possibly related https://www.overleaf.com/blog/changes-to-free-compile-timeouts-and-servers

Answer (score 2):

if you have a `latexmkrc` file in your project and add

```
$show_time=1;
```

Then look in cached files `output.stdout`  it will end something like this:

```
'pdflatex': time = 10.48
Processing time = 13.76
Number of rules run = 1
```

I got the warning here from the test document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\def\qqq{aaa \par\ifnum\value{page}<10000 \expandafter\qqq\fi}\qqq
\end{document}
```